# Как получить класс элемента, waypoint.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код

```
<div class="main-elements">
    <div class="main-item"></div>
    <div class="main-item"></div>
    <div class="main-item"></div>
    <div class="main-item"></div>
    <div class="main-item"></div>
  </div>
```

И такой js код

```
$(".main-item").waypoint(function() {
    var el = $(this)
    console.log(el)

  }, { offset: '100%'});
```

Однако console.log не выводит сам элемент html. Как получить именно элемент html дабы добавить именно ему класс

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто разобраться в структуре возвращаемого объекта:

```
  el[0].element
```